# Converting rate charge formula to C expression

Tags: c

A call is charged 30 cents per minute.
The cost for line rental is RM60.00. The tax for the overall bill including the line rental) is 15%.

Calculate the amount, that needs to be paid by the user given the number of
minutes that the user uses his/her mobile phone.

How can I transform this formula into C code?

```
rate = (minute*0.30)+15/100 *60
```

Comment: `float rate = ((60*0.30)+15)/100) * 60;` , maybe?

Comment: That formula is valid C code if you add a semicolon. It isn't correct, though, for purely mathematical reasons…

Comment: FWIW, "C Programming Problems" is not a very useful title.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. It might help you avoiding multiple downvotes on your next question.

Comment: `15/100` is 0.  (integer division)

Answer (score 3):

The formula is wrong. You first need to multiply the number of minutes by 30 cents, then add the 60 for the rental, and only then apply the tax by multiplying by 1.15:

```
int minutes = // inputted from user...
double total = ((0.3 * minutes) + 60) * 1.15;
```

Comment: Why 1.15? is this equivalent to 15%? 

Also, instead of using int can i replace with float? example: float minute;

Comment: 0.15 is 15% - but you don't want to calculate the tax, but the entire amount to pay, which would be 115% (100% the total amount plus 15%). And yes, you can use `float` for `minutes`, if you want to represent non-integer minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think is just that:

```
float minute;
float rate;
printf("How many minutes?");
scanf("%f", &minute);
rate = (minute * 0.3 + 60) + 0.15 * (minute * 0.3 + 60);
```

Comment: What's the benefit of separating the two components rather than just multiplying by 1.15?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler None, I did it this way to be easier to understand the steps of program